# Apple iPhone app update notification for specific users

Tags: ios

As far as I understand it, every time I release an update to my iPhone app, Apple somehow notifies all users of my app update.

Is there a way to selectively target certain users, as dictated by my server for example, to receive update notifications? So only users with the property 'X' would get a notification when a new version of the app was available.

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't notify anyone about your app update other than through the App Store app. There is nothing you can do to prevent this. All users will be able to access your update.

However, if you wanted, you could add a feature in your app that check your server to see if there is an update, and for some desired users you could show an alert letting the user know there is an update.

Comment: That's really helpful- would I be able to make that server-checking feature a push notification? So that the desired users would receive a notification outside of the context of the app once there is an update?

Comment: Sure, you could do it via push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such way. You can't manipulate the behavior of the App Store app.